# How does this prove that the set of positive integers is unbounded above

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, natural-numbers

This is a proof from Apostol's Calculus. What I don't understand about it is the "Hence, there is at least one positive integer n such that n > b - 1" Is it because for every inductive set (the positive integers in this case) x+1 also belongs to the set? It doesn't specify why, and it doesn't seem like it. I guess it actually has something to do with some property of the least upper bound, but I don't understand how.

[image: Image of the proof]

Comment: The phrasing "Hence, .." suggests that some reason has just been given.  Citing a page for your quotation will of course assist Readers in helping you.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Somehow forgot to add the photo

Comment: No, it follows from the definition of "least upper bound". If there wasn't a positive integer greater than $b-1$, then $b-1$ would also be an upper bound, but it is less than $b$ (you should check with your axioms and your understanding why this seemingly obvious fact is true), and that violates the properties that $b$ has as the least upper bound of $\mathbb P$. Like you thought, you might want to go re-read the definition of least upper bound again, and see how it works here.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Ok, and n+1 exists by the property of inductive sets I said, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant property here is that $b$ is the least upper bound.

Let us suppose on the contrary that there exists no $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $n > b - 1$. In that case, we see that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $n \leq b - 1$. But this is exactly what it would mean for $b - 1$ to be an upper bound of $\mathbb{Z}_+$. $b - 1$ cannot be an upper bound of $\mathbb{Z}_+$, since $b$ is the least upper bound and $b - 1 < b$. This is a contradiction.

Therefore, there must be some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $n > b - 1$. And we therefore see that $n + 1 > b$, which contradicts the claim that $b$ is an upper bound.

Comment: +1. Another way to say this is that if $b=lub \Bbb\, P$ then  $\forall n\in\Bbb P\,(b\ge n+1),$ implying $\forall n\in\Bbb P\,(b-1\ge n),$ implying $\Bbb P$ has an upper bound ($b-1$) that's less than its $lub$ $ (b)$, which is absurd.